# Make django-leaflet widget in admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, leaflet, django-widget

Can I make django-leaflet widget in admin if my model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as m
from djgeojson.fields import GeometryCollectionField

class Doc(m.Model):
    name = m.CharField()
    type = m.ForeignKey()
    geom = GeometryCollectionField()
```

If I'm try:

admin:

```
class DocAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = f.DocGeometryForm
...
```

forms:

```
class DocGeometryForm(f.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = m.Doc
        widgets = {
          'geom': LeafletWidget(),
        }

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all':('ext/leaflet/leaflet.css',)
        }
        js = [
            'ext/jquery/jquery.js',
            'ext/leaflet/leaflet.js',
        ]
```

Getting: l.map.djangomap is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @property
    def media(self):
        media = super(MyAdmin, self).media
        l = LeafletWidget()
        l.include_media = True
        return media + l.media
```